# MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() vs. REGEXP for matching whole words

Tags: mysql, regex, match-against

I am trying to optimise searching in my dictionary (109,000 entries, MyISAM, FULLTEXT), and I am now comparing the performance of `MATCH() AGAINST()` with that of `REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword1[[:>:]]' AND table.field REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword2[[:>:]]'`.

Using two keywords, I get (inside PhpMyAdmin) **0.0000 seconds** or **0.0010 seconds** for the `MATCH() AGAINST()` query vs. **0.1962 seconds** or **0.2190 seconds** for the regex query. Is speed the only indicator that matters here? Which query should I prefer (both appear to yield the exact same results)? Is it the obvious – the faster one?

Here are the full queries:

```
SELECT * FROM asphodel_dictionary_unsorted 
JOIN asphodel_dictionary_themes ON asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.theme_id = asphodel_dictionary_themes.theme_id 
LEFT JOIN asphodel_dictionary_definitions ON asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.term_id = asphodel_dictionary_definitions.term_id 
WHERE MATCH (asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english) 
AGAINST ('+boiler +pump' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM asphodel_dictionary_unsorted 
JOIN asphodel_dictionary_themes ON asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.theme_id = asphodel_dictionary_themes.theme_id 
LEFT JOIN asphodel_dictionary_definitions ON asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.term_id = asphodel_dictionary_definitions.term_id 
WHERE asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english REGEXP '[[:<:]]boiler[[:>:]]' 
AND asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english REGEXP '[[:<:]]pump[[:>:]]' 
ORDER BY asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.theme_id, asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english
```

Comment: If the answer (for this question) isn't obvious, then it's opinion based.

Comment: Agree. But I am not experienced enough in MySQL and I might be missing something, which is why I'm asking this.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm laughing. But compared to 99% of questions (**and** answers) on SO you are an expert (if you wrote those queries) :-)

Comment: Yes, I did (write them). Of course, after quite a bit of experimenting and reading. Thank you :)

Comment: There are cases where `FULLTEXT` won't work.  They mostly center around an abnormal definition of "word", or a language that does not mimic English closely enough for FT to work.  But when it works, FT is _much_ faster than `REGEXP` or `LIKE`.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, there are cases it won't work. And I'm already struggling with one. I'll probably post a new question about it – the three-letter minimum length restriction that won't return correct results when search for a phrase that includes a three-letter word, e.g. "return air". I assign a non-fulltext search to three-letter keywords automatically, but I don't know how to handle phrases where one of the words is three characters long.

Comment: Hmm... `match(ft) against('+return +air' in boolean mode)` works for me.  Please provide a test case that shows it failing for you.

Comment: I offer the user a choice of several search modes. The default is "any match". In it, my latest idea is to check if any of the keywords is three characters or less long, then I add an asterisk to it, then I implode the keywords and the query looks like this: `WHERE MATCH(asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english) AGAINST('return air*')`... the "return air" result is down the list but is preceded by "return" or "air"-containing results. Strangely, if I try `WHERE MATCH(asphodel_dictionary_unsorted.english) AGAINST('return cut*')`, this is the top result.

Comment: `('return run*')` and `('blast box*')` behave the same way as "return air", while `('above par*')` returns no results although the term exists. This is weird behaviour and I don't know what causes it. I have a separate search mode called "all whole words" where the search is exactly as you suggest, e.g. each keyword is preceded by a plus sign and `IN BOOLEAN MODE` added. Some queries behave as expected, some don't. I really have no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MATCH/AGAINST` solution uses a FULLTEXT index, and it searches the index pretty efficiently.

The `REGEXP` solution cannot use an index. It always forces a table-scan and tests every row with the regular expression. As your table grows, it will take longer to do `REGEXP` queries in linear proportion to the number of rows.

I did a presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) some years ago, where I compared fulltext-indexed approaches against `LIKE` and `REGEXP`. With sample data of 7.4 million rows, the `REGEXP` took 7 minutes, 57 seconds, whereas searching an InnoDB `FULLTEXT` index in boolean mode took 350 milliseconds — the `MATCH/AGAINST` query was 1,363 times faster.

The difference grows even larger the more rows you have.

Comment: My database isn't likely to grow, actually it will become a smaller as it currently contains many instances of the singular term and the plural term (in English) with the same singular translation in Bulgarian (more than half of entries already processed). But still, the difference between 0.0010 seconds and 0.2190 seconds is substantial. And this is all I wanted to know – if speed is the ultimate criterion here. Thank you.