# REGEXP alternative in MySQL for better performance

Tags: mysql

In a table, we have a column 'title' and we are using REGEXP to find any other similar title which matches any word of the first title, however, we are facing some performance issues while using the REGEXP to accomplish this requirement.

Can someone please suggest any other alternative to achieve the requirement?

Example:
title 1 = 'Human Resources Director'
we are trying to find other titles in the same tables with the below condition. So we need any other title that contains any one of the words(Human or Resources or Director).

```
SELECT id,title FROM table_name WHERE title REGEXP '\\bHuman\\b|\\bResources\\b|\\bDirector\\b'
```

Even though we have a separate index on the title it's not getting utilized.

Comment: Let's say your data is something like https://dbfiddle.uk/gZAZ5JW_ .. what is the expected result for that?

Comment: @FanoFN, Yes, that is the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

You can Use [FULL Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) To use Full-Text Search in MySQL, you need to create a FULLTEXT index on the column that you want to search. Once you have created the index, you can use the MATCH() function to perform the search. The [BOOLEAN MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) is used to specify that we want to perform a boolean search, which allows us to use the operators "+" and "-" to specify which words are required or excluded from the search.

```
 SELECT title FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('Human Resources Director' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Will the FULLTEXT index doesn't have any other performance impacts?

Comment: FULLTEXT is efficient compare to REGEXP for detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971966/mysql-match-against-vs-regexp-for-matching-whole-words

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/DF5n7EDt